New object creating multiple copies and somehow linked to other object instances in scene ,how to solve this?
In the scene used instances for creating 4 legs of an equipment like structure, after modeling some other part, I tried to add a cylinder but strangely it appears as 4 cylinder copies like the instances and selecting one of the cylinder copies showing that they connected to each legs I previously created. I can't add a new object to this scene ,how to solve this issue ?
EDIT; For clarification Object added in Object mode not in edit mode ,when adding object in edit mode copies doubles to 8.in picture cube is added in object mode and cylinder is added in edit mode


It sounds as if you added the cylinder in Edit mode rather than Object mode. If so it will be part of the leg mesh and will inherit the legs settings and modifiers.

created in Object mode ,I tried once again to ensure

tried edit mode just for curiosity then the number of cylinder became 8 instead of 4 in object mode.

I think we'd need to see your full Blender window including the Outliner in that case and also your Blend file to see what's going on. (My main HD crashed this afternoon so I don't have access to Blender here at the moment.)

Thank you for your response ,Sorry for your HD, crash, Post updated with full window scene , cube added in object mode and cylinder  in edit mode,I am following a hard surface tutorial I don't know how I messed up like this .

The selected object is a collection.

As @lemon says the selected 'object' in the Outliner is a Collection. If you hit the little arrow to the left of it to open it you'll see that it contains the new objects that you've added. If you just want to add a single unconnected object you'll need to hilight the root Collection in the Outliner (which is currently out of view) and then add your new object.

@John Eason Thank you so much  ,by clicking scene collection now I can create new object  without any copies .But how to separate the already created multiple objects because they  showing in outliner only  as a collection ' white box icon inside a double orange box' not as usual individual inverted triangle icons [post Image updated}
